# How to update dataTable using requestscoped wrapper bean in JSF?

Tags: jsf, session, datatable, request, updating

I have mainMenu-xhtml page where is Datatable. When I add a new object to that table, it is not updating because used managed bean is session scoped. I am trying to implement requestScoped wrapperBean to make updating happening.

**Faces-config:**

```
<navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{RmaBeanWrapper.submit}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>refreshedMainMenu</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/mainMenu.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>RmaBeanWrapper</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>fi.controllers.RmaBeanWrapper</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>rmaBean</property-name>
        <value>#{RmaBean}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

**RmaBeanWrapper**

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class RmaBeanWpapper implements Serializable  {

private RmaBean rmaBean;
private RmaBean refreshedBean;

public RmaBean getRmaBean() {
    return rmaBean;
}

public void setRmaBean(RmaBean rmaBean) {
    this.rmaBean = rmaBean;
}

public RmaBean getRefreshedBean() {
    return refreshedBean;
}

public void setRefreshedBean(RmaBean refreshedBean) {
    this.refreshedBean = refreshedBean;
}


public String submit() {
   System.out.println("#########RmaBeanWpapper.submit#########"); 
   this.refreshedBean = rmaBean;

    return "refreshedMainMenu";

}
```

**mainMenu.xhtml**

```
<p:panelGrid style="margin-top:20px;" styleClass="noBorders">
                <p:row rendered="true">
                    <p:column></p:column>
                    <p:column></p:column>
                    <p:column><p:commandButton action="#{RmaBeanWpapper.submit}" ajax="false" value="Update Table" style="width: 220px;"/></p:column>
                    <p:column></p:column>
                </p:row>
```

}

What is happening? Nothing! The mainMenu.xhtml page doesn't even open, and there is not even any exceptions in the servers log. Samehow I have to get my table updated, but there is something wrong with my implementation. Any ideas? I can't change rmaBean to sessionScoped, because is is used everywhere in the software and I can't change it.

Cheers,
Sami

Comment: You can start by removing the managed-bean from the faces-config.xml when you are using annotations.

Comment: Actually I deleted annotation :)